# Converting a raw string into a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of data consisting of daily measurements of two parameters.  The data is available as a list of strings.  Different parameters are measured each day.  In the sample below, on January 1, a parameter "ab" has the value 100 and "c" has the value 101. (My data has undesirably split the names of the parameters wherever the name contains more than one word.)

```
lis = {"January","1","a","b","100","c","101","January","2","c","de","f","102","g","h",103"}
```

and would like to convert this to:

```
res ={{DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}],"ab","100","c","101"},{DateObject[{2020,1,2}],"cdef","102","gh","103"}}
```

In this data, there is always a day number following a month name.  The parameter names are always preceded and followed by numbers and need to be combined into a single string element. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you really really sure that you can no longer fix the original and prevent the splitting? This is a pretty horrible format, and a lot of work. Also, how come "de" did not get split?

Comment: Also, what happened to e.g. January 10? Did it become `{"January", "1", "0"}`, or `{"January", "10"}`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gosh, what a mess! Pretty much the only thing that could be easily recognized is the month names, so let's start from there to tokenize the list of strings.

I have added another example to your list, just to make sure that it works for more than two examples, and defined a list of months:

```
list = {"January", "1", "a", "b", "100", "c", "101", 
        "January", "2", "c", "de", "f", "102", "g", "h", "103", 
        "February", "20", "a", "b", "20"};

months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", 
          "May", "June", "July", "August", 
          "September", "October", "November", "December"};
```

Start by finding the month names and using them as delimiters to split the list:

```
Flatten@Position[list, _String?(MemberQ[months, #] &)]~
  Join~{Length[list] + 1};
Range[#1, #2 - 1] & @@@ Partition[%, 2, 1];
chopped = list[[#]] & /@ %

(* Out: 
{{"January", "1", "a", "b", "100", "c", "101"}, 
 {"January", "2", "c", "de", "f", "102", "g", "h", "103"}, 
 {"February", "20", "a", "b", "20"}} *)
```

The use an `Interpreter` to turn the first two strings, guaranteed to be month and day, to a `DateObject`:

```
dated = Cases[
    chopped,
    {month_, day_, rest__} :> {Interpreter["Date"][StringJoin[month, day]], rest}
 ]

(* Out: 
 {{DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], "a", "b", "100", "c", "101"},
  {DateObject[{2020, 1, 2}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], "c", "de", "f", "102", "g", "h", "103"}, 
  {DateObject[{2020, 2, 20}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], "a", "b", "20"}} 
*)
```

Finally define a conversion function that uses `ToExpression` to convert each token, then decide whether the converted form is a string (i.e. a measurement *name*), or a number (i.e. a measurement *value*); in the latter case, it returns the number, otherwise it returns the string.

```
ClearAll[converter]
converter[s_String] :=
  StringCases[s,
    PatternSequence[
      name : Repeated[LetterCharacter],
      value : Repeated[DigitCharacter]
    ] :> Sequence[name, ToExpression[value]]
  ]
```

... and apply it to the previous result:

```
Cases[
  dated,
  {date_DateObject, strings__} :> {date, Sequence @@ converter@StringJoin[strings]}
]

(* Out: 
 {{DateObject[{2020, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], "ab", 100, "c", 101}, 
  {DateObject[{2020, 1, 2}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], "cdef", 102, "gh", 103}, 
  {DateObject[{2020, 2, 20}, "Day", "Gregorian", -6.`], "ab", 20}} 
*)
```

Comment: Yes it is a mess.  But thanks for a start at it.

Comment: @Suite401 You are welcome. See my update answer: it should solve the whole problem.

Comment: Thanks! a lot to study here.

Answer (score 4):

A variation on Syed's approach:

```
f = {DateObject["2020," <> # <> #2],
     ## & @@ StringSplit[StringJoin @##3, x : NumberString :> x]} & @@@ 
    Split[#, Not @ StringMatchQ[#2, DatePattern[{"MonthName"}]] &] &;

f @ lis
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Let me share a belated answer (as part of my learning process) using non-`Sequence` functions. The choice of the year used is arbitrary.

```
lis = {"January", "1", "a", "b", "100", "c", "101", "January", "2", 
  "c", "de", "f", "102", "g", "h", "103"};

months = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
   "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};

Join[{
    DateObject[{2020, Det@Position[months, #[[1]]], 
      ToExpression@#[[2]]}, "Day"],
    Sequence @@ 
     StringJoin @@@ SplitBy[#[[3 ;;]], StringMatchQ[#, NumberString] &]
    }] & /@ Split[lis, FreeQ[months, #2] &]
```

[image]